# Start React server container without Nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I need advice from someone who really understands React app dockerization.

I will be as brief as I can.

We have 3 containers now -- DB, backend, frontend.

Our Frontend Dockerfile is below:

```
FROM node:16-buster-slim as builder

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# add app
COPY . ./

RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine

RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY localconf /etc/nginx

COPY --from=builder /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./env-config.* ./
COPY ./env.sh .

RUN chmod +x env.sh

RUN apk add --no-cache bash openssl 
    
RUN chmod +x env.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "env && /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

**The whole problem is that developers can't track changes in real time with this container. They run frontend on the host machine with `yarn build && yarn start` and when the changes are stable and ready, they build the container.**

Now I need help to investigate why new container is not working.

I have reduced the Dockerfile to the following :

```
FROM node:16-buster-slim

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# add app
COPY . ./

RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

And to watch changes in real time I added volume at `docker-compose.yaml file`:

```
frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ../../client/project
      dockerfile: local.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: yarn start
    env_file:
      - ../../client/project/.env
    volumes:
      - ../../client/project:/app/
      - /app/node_modules
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

I don't know why, but application doesn't respond on any request and refuse any connection to localhost:443, where it works fine with Nginx.

***So, please, could you tell some best-practices to Deckerize React App without Nginx to check real-time changes?***

I know for sure it is not an unusual task, but I didn't find anything with Docs or Google.

[image]

Comment: You describe a best practice in your question already: install Node on your host if it's not there already, and use `yarn start` to run the application locally (without Docker involved).

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you tell please why it is more appropriate to use nginx if it less comfortable. (we don't speak about production version where nginx is necessary)

Comment: You don't need it in a typical development setup.  Run `yarn build && yarn start` and do development normally without Docker.  When the changes are stable and ready, build an image to do integration testing; at that point you'd bring in the Nginx proxy.

Answer (score 0):

When the "yarn start" command is launched, it refers to your "package.json" -> "script" -> "start"
I suggest you install the "nodemon" package like this:

```
yarn add nodemon
```

nodemon allows the server to be restarted each time the files are updated
Create the following line in your package.json:

```
{
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www.js",
     ...
   }
   ...
}
```

To replace "./bin/www.js" by the entry point of your application
In your Dockerfile change

```
CMD["yarn", "start"]
```

by

```
CMD["yarn", "dev"]
```

Which would give:

```
FROM node:16-buster-slim

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# add app
COPY . ./

RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your solution, but where do you suggest use line `yarn add nodemon`?  I dont see it in final version of Dockerfile

Comment: You are using a package.json file which means you have to run the "yarn add nodemon" command at the root of your project. So nodemon will be added to package.json

Comment: Hello, just to clarify when you write `To replace "./bin/www.js" by the entry point of your application` you mean `npm start` ?